# Is it possible to access and set an emails Information Rights Management using EWS when creating a new email?

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I need to create a new email with permission set to "Do Not Forward" using EWS. But I cant find permission property for the message object. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EWS can be used to access/set the data within in Email, it doesn't have however the ability to perform the Client Side encryption required by RMS to read or write. There is an RMS SDK for doing the RMS side https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rights-management/develop/overview

Outlook offers an easy to use solution in that it just a few lines of code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.permissiontemplateguid.aspx and Outlook itself provides the client side certificate enrolment.

Cheers
Glen